# Elm: how does Mailbox work?

Tags: elm

Say I create a `Mailbox` using `mailbox = Signal.mailbox Action`, where `type Action = Blah`, later I can send actions to this `mailbox` using `Signal.send mailbox.address Blah`, this allows me to listen on `mailbox.signal`, how so? I mean, after all, type `Mailbox` is just an alias of `{address : Signal.Address Action, signal : Signal.Signal Action}`, is it because that, in elm, there is only one signal for a certain type, so in the above scenario, I don't have to tell elm to bind `mailbox.signal` with `mailbox.address`, elm will figure out itself because of the one-to-one correspondence between the address and signal of a certain type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ability for mailbox to put events you send to it into its signal is entirely based on "magic", that is, it's implemented natively (in JavaScript) and not something you could implement yourself. That's why it's a built-in in the standard libraries.

Creating a mailbox is an imperative, effectful action (shhh, don't tell anyone). So if you use:

```
mailbox1 = Signal.mailbox Blah
mailbox2 = Signal.mailbox Blah
```

those two mailboxes will be distinct. Send a message to `mailbox2.address` will result in a message on `mailbox2.signal` but not `mailbox1.signal`. This breaks referential transparency, which is bad, but for now it's not breaking everything. (This may go too far into a tangent, but because you need `Signal` for output and can't have `Signal (Signal something)`, in practice the unmanaged effect of mailbox creation is not messing things up). This "leak" will be fixed at some point in the future. There was a proposal already but big changes are staged in different versions of the language.

Comment: If calling `Signal.mailbox` twice creates two different mailboxes, how does the code in [Communicating with Mailboxes](http://elm-lang.org/guide/reactivity) tutorial, i.e. `Signal.send contentMailbox.address "hello!"` work? Since `contentMailbox` is called a second time there, it should create a different signal which is not the one used in `main = Signal.map show contentMailbox.signal`  where it is called a first time and hence _"hello"_ should not show up?